# div within another div (css positioning)

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

This should be a pretty simple one. I need the 'orange' div to always cover 100% width and 100% height.

Within that div I need the 'green' div to also fill 100% width and height of it's parent, the 'orange' div.

Additionally there needs to always be 10px of 'padding' inside the 'orange' div.

**When the window is resized, each div must 'resize' respectively so that there are no scrollbars.**

http://jsfiddle.net/URwpA/3/

Comment: The orange div cannot have padding if you want the green div to fill completely.

Comment: How can I keep a constant 10px between the two might be a better question.

Comment: What browsers do you need this to work in?

Comment: @Marko ie7 and up, chrome, firefox (the usual ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First way:

```
#hold {
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 right:0px;
 background:orange;
 padding:10px;
}
#held {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:green;
}
```

Second way:

```
#hold {
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 right:0px;
 background:orange;
}
#held {
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:10px;
 bottom:10px;
 right:10px;
 background:green;
}
```

EDIT: The only way I can think of to achieve a layout that I think is being requested in the comment is as follows:

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
  <body style="height: 100%;">
    <table style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 10px solid orange; background-color: green;">
      <!-- etc... -->
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could one do the same thing with a table element without having its contents leak outside the wrapper div?

Comment: @captainrad I think I might need to see an updated fiddle to understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this?

```
#hold {
position:fixed;
background:orange;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:10px;
}
#held {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:green;
}
```

Comment: I need the padding to be on the right side as well as on the bottom. That doesn't show up for me in chrome or firefox.